# Angular typescript disable special characters in the input

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-zorro-antd

I'm using my angular project for ant design ng Zorro , I have some issue in he validation so when I set to input filed to special characters not allowed validation, but key press its doesn't working, any one know some solution?

**html**

```
<nz-form-item >
                <nz-form-control nzErrorTip="Company name is required!" >
                  <input

                    nz-input
                    placeholder="Type here"
                    formControlName="companyName"
                    nzSize="small"
                  />
                </nz-form-control>
              </nz-form-item>
```

**.ts**

```
 this.validateForm = this.fb.group(
 companyName: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z \-\']')]],
)
```

Comment: It won't restrict you typing anything _invalid_, but rather show an error if you do and blur the input. That's the desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't working probably because you are missing {}. fb.group() accepts object

it should be:

```
this.validateForm = this.fb.group({
      companyName: [null, [Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z \-\']')]],
    }
```

working example [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-zorro-antd-ivy-f5pac8?file=src/app/app.component.ts)